# Tailwind CSS not working with javascript variables for backgroundImage class

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, tailwind-css

We are using Tailwind CSS for our NextJs app and having issues while using `backgroundImage property` with javascript variable. Due to that we have to use it like this which is not encouraged as coding practices:

```
className={clsx("absolute top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-100% md:hidden")}
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${customBgImageMobile})` }} //don't want to use style here
```

We don't want to use `style attribute` here and want to use Tailwind CSS class's **backgroundImage** property.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since TailwindCSS statically analyzes your files to find strings of class names, you would need to make the variable itself contain the full TailwindCSS class name, or otherwise TailwindCSS won't know about it:

```
const customBgImageMobileClass = `bg-[url(<your image link here>)]` // note that you can't put the actual URL variable here; it needs to be the actual link itself
```

and then add that class variable to the `className` property.

Alternatively, you can add the URL to your `tailwind.config.cjs` file (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme):

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'image-mobile': "url('<your url>')",
      }
    }
  }
}

// and then in HTML <div className="bg-image-mobile"></div>
```